# Can “zum” be used to contract “zu einem”?

Tags: preposition, article, contractions

I know you can use it to shorten to *zu dem*, but is it also used for the indefinite article?

And is *zur* a different matter?

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot.

You could say

> "zu 'nem" 
>   / "zu 'ner"

instead, but this is exclusively used in spoken language.

Comment: What about _Kann ich Dich zum/zu einem Essen einladen?_ or _Wegen Deines Blutdrucks solltest Du zum/zu einem Arzt gehen._ That works for me.

Comment: @PerlDog In both cases you would use zum as a definite article. In *zum Essen einladen* the *Essen* is the nominalized form of *essen* so it is actually *dem Essen*. With *zum Arzt gehen* you normally mean a specific doctor namely your family doctor.

Comment: @RainbowRevenge _zum_ is indeed rather definite in the examples, yet it cannot be replaced by _zu dem_ or _zu diesem_ without subtly changing the meaning, whereas _zu einem_ works, so the Gerhard’s answer “no” is not really wrong, but too broad, because sometimes it’s “yes”.

Comment: @Crissov: The answer to the question "Can 'zum' be used to contract 'zu einem'" is always "no". I agree that one can say "jdn. zu einem Essen einladen", but this has a different meaning from "jdn. zum Essen einladen" , and hence "zum" is not a contraction of "zu einem". Instead, one would say "jdn. zu 'nem Essen einladen". Or did I misunderstand you here?

Comment: My point is that _jmd. zu**m** Essen einladen_ is semantically much closer to _jmd. zu **[ei]nem** Essen einladen_ than _jmd. zu **d[ies]em** Essen einladen_. If it really was a contraction here, _zum_ would in fact expand to _zu einem_. We could argue ad infinitum whether it actually is a contraction.

Comment: This would make a brilliant new question... - but I don't think it adds anything to the original question here, as "zum" in this case is still "definite", even though I agree that it has to some extent changed its meaning to be more general. But as I mentioned above "zu einem Essen einladen" has a very different connotation than "zum Essen einladen".

Answer (score 0):

The contractions *zum, zur* and also *im, am,* etc. cannot be expanded in any other way than with the definite article. The indefinite articles will not form contractions of that form.

In spoken language, many will shorten the indefinite articles separately, often to *’nem* (for *einem*) or *’ner* (for *einer*). Bavarian goes even further by saying *am* or *a(ra)*, respectively. However, adding those onto *zu* will never create *zum*, only *zu ’nem* or *zu am*.

Similarly, in English *we’re* can never mean *we were*, only ever *we are*, even though both verb forms end on the same letters.